# How to create a new column with a tuple (or a list)?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following DataFrame:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [10,20,30], 'b': [1,2,3] })

    a  b
0  10  1
1  20  2
2  30  3
```

I want to create a new column 'c' that will contain a tuple of 'a' and 'b' (per row). Something like this:

```
    a  b      c
0  10  1  (10,1)
1  20  2  (20,2)
2  30  3  (30,3)
```

I just can't make it, no matter what I try (I tried `apply` with `axis=1` and have it return a tuple, a list, a Series object.. neither worked).

I saw that I can create a DataFrame and set the dtype to 'object' and then I can put tuples in a cell. How do I do it with `apply`?

What I'm trying to do is to count distinct combinations of a and b, get the most common and print a summary with some data on them (data comes from other columns, let's say 'd' and 'e').
Is there any more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it using `zip`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10,20,30], 'b': [1,2,3]})
>>> df["c"] = zip(df["a"], df["b"])
>>> df
    a  b        c
0  10  1  (10, 1)
1  20  2  (20, 2)
2  30  3  (30, 3)

[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

but usually putting a tuple in a column is the wrong way to go because `pandas` can't really do anything else with it at that point.  If you want to count distinct combinations of `a` and `b` and do something with the associated groups of rows, you should use `groupby` instead:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [10,20,30,20,30], 'b': [1,2,3,2,1]})
>>> df
    a  b
0  10  1
1  20  2
2  30  3
3  20  2
4  30  1

[5 rows x 2 columns]
>>> df_counts = df.groupby(["a", "b"]).size()
>>> df_counts.sort(ascending=False)
>>> df_counts
a   b
20  2    2
30  3    1
    1    1
10  1    1
dtype: int64
```

"Print a summary with some data on them" is too broad to say anything useful about, but you can use `groupby` to perform all sorts of summary operations on the groups.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't aware of groupby. It indeed seems like the right thing to use. Will give it a try